# Error in Matplotlib in legend

Tags: matplotlib

If I include this `plt.legend(['$0.25+\zeta$'], loc = 1)`in my code, I am not getting
error. But `plt.legend(['$\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\alpha}{10}$'], loc = 1)` gives error.

Comment: Does `plt.legend([r'$\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\alpha}{10}$'], loc = 1)` work?

Comment: Yes, it is working! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sidenote, I think this would have been better suited at [so] actually, because it seems like purely a Python problem. Unless you tell `matplotlib` to do so, `matplotlib` doesn't actually use TeX at all, it has just implemented a subset of the language. (Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474322/ though.)